# Is this Normal when starting Blender?

Tags: command-line

Whenever I start Blender, this console window keeps popping up!
I'm not that techy with devices, is there anything I should do to stop it?
[image: this shows up at start]

Comment: It is completely normal on windows, I get it too. I don't see the point in removing it, as it should disappear in 1/2 a second after blender fully opens.

Comment: As you said, it lasts a bit of a second, but I didn't see that on my previous device. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

As other users said, this is normal. Do not try to remove this.